# Running a program on a server

Tags: java, android

I want to build an Android application that downloads an XML file from a web server and displays its contents in a readable format.
My problem is generating that XML file. Basically I want to run a program, say, every 30 minutes that downloads a web page (as that data is not easily accessible), parses it, generates said XML file and puts it somewhere for the Android application to download.
Now, I was writing a Java application to do this, but it came to me: where am I going to run this? I thought of having a laptop permanently running at home, but there must be a better alternative.
I have online hosting, but it is very simple. It does not even include SSH.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** as per your suggestions, I checked and yes, my cPanel does have a "Cron Jobs" section. I will now investigate it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you atleast have `cron`? Some hosters include cron front-ends even if you don't have ssh access.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have shell access, see if they will let you run a cron job.  If no, you will probably need to upgrade to someplace that does, or use your own machine.

Comment: I would try to write this server side code in PHP if possible since almost all cheap host service offer PHP support.  From what i know Java hosting will cost you more. And your host probably don't offer java support!  But as long as you have a cPanel with a cron jobs, you will be able to run a script that do the thing.

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you use to generate your XML. You could do everything you say you want with a one-line `awk` script. You could go "ghetto" (and cheap) and use your laptop to generate the XML file and upload it to your hosted server. Then your account is only dealing with a static file, which all of them support.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.setcronjob.com/ allows you to trigger a web page request once every hour, which might be good enough.

I have not actually tried it, but it sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rent a server which will generate your html and also serve the content to your app.  Not expensive if you get a VPS or cloud server.